# No main module initializer was specified (possibly because no or multiple main classes were found)

Tags: scala.js

Using the following project structure:

project/build.properties:

```
sbt.version = 1.1.4
```

project/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.22")
```

build.sbt:

```
enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)

name := "scalajs_example"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.6"
```

and src/main/scala/my/Main.scala:

```
package my

class Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello world")
  }
}
```

I get the following error when executing `sbt run`:

> [error] No main module initializer was specified (possibly because no
>   or multiple main classes were found), but
>   scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer was set to true. You can explicitly
>   specify it either with `mainClass := Some(...)` or with
>   `scalaJSMainModuleInitializer := Some(...)` [error] (Compile /
>   scalaJSModuleInitializers) No main module initializer was specified
>   (possibly because no or multiple main classes were found), but
>   scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer was set to true. You can explicitly
>   specify it either with `mainClass := Some(...)` or with
>   `scalaJSMainModuleInitializer := Some(...)`

Adding `mainClass := Some("my.Main")` to build.sbt and reloading the project did not help, same error remain when tried `sbt run` (`scalaJSMainModuleInitializer := Some(...)` - I could not figure out what to put to the `...`).

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with the using `class Main` instead of `object Main`. After the change, it works as expected:

```
[info] Running my.Main
Hello world
```

with or without explicitly specifying `mainClass` (it seems specifying an invalid main class will still find the only good one).